# Shutil.copy too slow for downloading files located in remote network path

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I am trying to download some html files located in a remote server path.
The code which I am using is:

```
for f in list_of_files:       
   shutil.copy(f, local_folder)
```

`list_of_files` is basically a list containing entries like

```
\\remote_server_name\directory\x.html
```

Is it possible to get the performance comparable to <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>?

Other SO posts on this topic is for copying text content from one file to other. Mine is different problem I believe.